# iteration isn't working- loop skipped - do while

Tags: vba, range

My code give below is intended to do the following go to B1 , Select B2:B10 , delete all values in this B2:B10 range. 
go to B11 & then Select B12:B21, delete all values in this range

```
Sub gk()
Dim j As Long
Range("B1").Select
Do While j = 5
j = j + 1
ActiveCell.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1 & ":B" & ActiveCell.Row + 10).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

But this isn't working . Code is skipping the picking the range part . please help.

Comment: `Dim j As Long`. So `j` is 0. `Do While j = 5` -> skips right through, `j` is not 5.

Comment: you can clear them all at once `Range("B2:B10,B12:B21,B23:B32").ClearContents`

Comment: thanks @Mat'sMug..

 I've missed the syntax as explained by callumDA

Comment: I would'nt have written code if it were only 3 set of ranges @slai . I need to somehow automate, otherwise would be doing 2000+ iterations manually. Regards!

Comment: Protip: next time try to work a bit harder on figuring it out on your own (even if it means talking to a [rubber duck](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)), to ask a question that can be useful to others (people tend to land on SO after googling their coding problem) - and you'll get *upvotes* instead of down & close votes ;-)

Comment: I'll keep that suggestion in mind @Mat'sMug. I would've gone to quora for upvotes, this is my learning platform and some more novice coders may get help from my silly mistakes. You never know that !!

Comment: Upvotes matter! Each question upvote gets you +5 rep, and each answer upvote gets you +10 rep; your reputation score is what unlocks site privileges, and upvoting good/useful answers is *the* best way to say "thanks!" to someone on Stack Overflow - take the [tour] for all the details. Note that the systen can block your account from asking if your contributions are consistently not well-received; votes on SO control content quality... we're quite far, far away from the Quora model. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: @Mat'sMug point taken !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting this here because its *so* quick to fix, really you should find this error quite quickly if you were Googling how to use this `While` loop

```
Sub gk()
    Dim j As Long
    Range("B1").Select
    Do While j <= 5 'this is the line you need to update
        j = j + 1
        ActiveCell.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1 & ":B" & ActiveCell.Row + 10).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: IMO it's more a case of "[tell the rubber ducky what your code does, step by step](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)" than anything else.

Comment: Thanks @CallumDA . My brain went into 'Do until' loop, I've missed simple syntax.

Comment: first week coding @Mat'sMug .. I'm happy about these screw-ups.. 

doesn't matter ! 
anyways, thanks

Comment: @G.K no problem - do read that article about rubber duck debugging though, it's got excellent debugging tips!